# Improving curl performance

Tags: curl

I'm using a class written by someone else to try to connect to a website that's not mine, it's something like http://www.futhead.com, where you are able to search for players and such using the EA JSON files.

However the page and scripting works but it takes 4/5 sec to load every time.

I think this might be due to the use of curl, I've looked here for some answers but none didn't really improve anything.
Are there any other options to improve speed?

```
$ch = curl_init($login);                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Have you tested to make sure that curl is the problem, and it's not just general network slowness?  You can view the time curl used for the transfer with `-w, --write-out time_total`

Comment: Er... in php, `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME)`

Comment: it gave me back '2.407344' second time it was '1.970534'
if that's seconds the page still takes longer to load but i do have other curls to, further down the page.

Comment: Ok, half the script's time is consumed by the internet.  You could echo out the system time before and after you start and end curl, and whatever time you're left with is just the speed of your server.

Comment: system time gives me 3,5 seconds before and after the curl.

Comment: All classes being used can be found here 
https://github.com/mousey/FIFA13-Ultimate-Team-Search/tree/master/code
the one i'm referring to right now is connector.php, but all other pages are also using it, perhaps a complete look at the page might help you find out what the problem is..

Answer (score 1):

You could try running that curl request less often.  If it happens every time you hit a page, that's probably too often.

You could put more ram and cores in your server, and you could get a better ISP for it.

About your github code....the Q&A format isn't really supposed to be for open, "fix-my-code" type questions.  It seems to me that you have many sources of time consumption, and your code may be involved...but mostly it's network stuff.  I don't have a good answer for making curl run faster (except for getting better connectivity).

**Edit:  Questioner has made attempts to improve his server's performance:**

It's time to admit that you need to refactor.  I did read through your connection, and in your `Connector` class function `connect()`, you make four sequential curl operations.  Each time, you deliberately (but necessarily?) close the curl handle.  You're talkign to the same server every time, right?

You need to change your code en masse.  It happens to the best of us.

Comment: i can't really run less curls, i need a curl to login, a curl to recieve our amount of coins and a curl to look players up and such, i'm not a super pro php'er but that just 'as far as i know', i didn't link the github for someone to fix my code, just to perhaps help you get a better understanding of it.

i would love for someone to help me find it so i can learn from it and tell me what can be done better, not just fix it. i'm working on xampp at the moment and using the best macbook Retina so i think hardware wise is not the problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking for help.  I just think your question would fare better somewhere other than this site.  I'll even take a 2nd look at your code.  If you see a pull request from me...accept it, I guess.  :)

Comment: no problem.  Also, a macbook running Xampp is far from a high-performance server, no matter how good the hardware is.  You might scrape some performance by running the native apache/mysql in osX, or better yet by adding ubuntu server to your bootcamp and developing there.  Xampp doesn't even reccomend itself for anything except development purposes: http://serverfault.com/questions/149165/is-it-recommended-to-use-xamppsoftware-bundle-on-production-environment-and-wh

Comment: i'll try using hosting or native apache to test if it increases speeds.

Comment: i used your advice but it did not solve my problem still slow loading webpages =(